# Explicitly initialize DWORD to 1, but debugger shows wildly out of range value

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dword

I'm a bit flabberghasted with this issue - in debug mode this issue doesn't come up at all, but in release mode it feels like there's almost nothing I can do to fix it.

Here's a screenshot of what's going on inside VS2013:

[image]

I initialize `nResult` to 1L, and the internal value is shown as 3422785012. In Debug mode, this value is indeed 1L.

Any ideas as to why the displayed value isn't even close to the initial value I set for `nResult`? I've tried playing with compiler settings - in Debug mode this code runs fine.

Comment: Watch info is not reliable in Release mode. Does the code still execute correctly?

Comment: @dlf it does not - I have diagnostic logging that writes output to the filesystem, and the value of dword varies pretty wildly in release mode.

Comment: If you log nResult to a file at the exact spot you indicated, do you get something other than 1? That would indeed be pretty surprising.

Comment: @dlf you know what - just realized that the debug output I was looking at was from a previous build. I did a full rebuild and indeed, the correct output is being produced.

Comment: @JohnDibling fixed it now - apparently there was an unrelated bug that only occurred in Release mode that made it look as though this DWORD value was the culprit, since this DWORD was responsible for storing the exit code for a child process. After adding some explicit logging for the DWORD itself I was able to isolate it to a previous test run that had not cleaned up properly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code is more than likely `optimized`.  This means that the compiler has moved and eliminated code in a way that your source code does not match what the compiler has produced.

Either debug unoptimized code, or debug optimized code with the full knowledge that the source may not match the actual instructions being performed.

If you want to debug a release build but see the correct values in the debugger, go to the Properties of your project in Visual Studio, go to the C/C++ section, and disable the optimizations.  Rebuild.

Answer (score 3):

Debugging release code is quite difficult as the compiler will reorder, remove, inline and rearrange things.

The only reliable way to debug a "release" build is to leave all release options enabled, but disable code optimizations. Or you could just disable optimizations in any modules you want full debugging info from. I've seen this done in the past when a bug was impossible to track down in a fully optimized released x64 build, as x64 clobbers the parameters far more often than x86 (when looking at crash dumps).