# Getting <Bad Ptr> and invalid values when assigning values to CString

Tags: c++, mfc, variable-assignment

I am trying to assign some simple text to my CString variables.  The CStrings are member variables for Edit Controls in MFC.

I am assigning the following values with code as follows:

```
BOOL CImageDisplay::OnInitDialog()
{

...  //Has nothing to do with the email variables

m_mailTo = "example@domain.com";
m_mailSubject = "Admin Options Test Email Subject";
m_mailBody = "This is a test email sent from Admin Options.";
return true;
}
```

The values show **correctly** in my GUI.  My problem is that when I debug my program, my values are immediately incorrect.  I have a < Bad Ptr> for my first value.  My second variable has the value I assigned to my first varaible, as so forth:

> m_mailTo = Bad Ptr
>
> m_mailSubject = "example@domain.com"
>
> m_mailBody = Admin Options Test Email Subject"

I do not understand why my variables hold these values when I clearly set them.    Thanks for any help to this confusing problem!

*I can add more code if necessary, I just didn't want to flood the page if it was not needed.*

Comment: Somehow, the PDB file (the debugging information) is stale. Try doing 
Build > Rebuild Solution

Comment: If you're debugging a release build, expect variables to be optimized away and the debugger showing you "wrong" values.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348983/explicitly-initialize-dword-to-1-but-debugger-shows-wildly-out-of-range-value

Comment: I think you may be correct that the debugging information is stale... I tried using the values in a send email function. Although (in the debugger) it says that the value of 'm_mailTo' is "Bad Ptr", the email is sent to correctly to whoever I set mailTo as...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Using Rebuild Solution worked.  If you could, type up your comment as an answer.  This may be helpful for someone else. I will choose it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Igor Tandetnik stated, my PDB file (the debugging information) was stale.  Although I was receiving invalid debugging values, they were actually correct.
This was fixed by going to *build -> Rebuild Solution*.