# Visual C++ if statement. The breakpoint will not currently be hit

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, programming in C++ and have a base class with the following attribute:

```
ref class AI
{

...

protected:

   /// <summary>
   /// Exit found flag. False if exit is yet to be found, true if it already was.
   /// </summary>
   bool exitFound;

...

}
```

Within the derived class I have the following code:

```
void AI_II::analyze(void)
{

...

        this->exitFound = true;

        if (this->exitFound)
        {
            if (this->distFront->lastTile == EXIT){...}
            else if (this->distDown->lastTile == EXIT){...}
            else if (this->distBack->lastTile == EXIT){...}
            else if (this->distUp->lastTile == EXIT){...}
        }

...

}
```

And I don't know how, but when running or debugging, the `if (this->exitFound)` statement is always skipped. When debugging I get the "The breakpoint will not currently be hit..." message.

I already tried to clean the solution, but no success so far. Anyone can help me find what is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're not debugging a release (optimized) build? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348983/explicitly-initialize-dword-to-1-but-debugger-shows-wildly-out-of-range-value/23349047#23349047

Answer (score 2):

Select in Visual Studio [Properties] - [Build] tab and check [Define DEBUG constant] and [Define TRACE constant] are checked. Also check [Debug Info] is set to [full] in [Advanced] tab.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! It was just a compiler optimization problem.