# Break points in debug, jumps automatically to other code. MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, breakpoints

Does anybody come across this funny situation ? I am sending some messages to the window handlers using "SendMessage" MFC-API. In debugging, I came to know that, the messages are not going to the appropriate methods, even though the handler are different. (We can check addresses while debug right.. ;).

For example, I have two classes 1.cpp, 2.cpp . Both has two methods 1::method() , 2::method(). Now, even though I send handler to call 1::method, 2::method() is getting called.

Surprisingly, When I tried to put a break point in 1::method(), the break point is automatically jumped to the 2::method(). (The break point is moved visually to the other source file).

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. Now can anybody explain why this happens ?

Comment: Are you [debugging an optimized build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348983/explicitly-initialize-dword-to-1-but-debugger-shows-wildly-out-of-range-value/23349047#23349047)?

Comment: No. All optimizations are disabled. Project settings are in Active Release with Debug settings .

Comment: `SendMessage` is used with window handles, not classes. Your question fails to make a connection between them, and it's hard to understand, what you are really doing. You probably should provide the real code, instead of describing it.

Comment: provide some code, it might help

Comment: Got a small clue.. When ever compiler knows that the code where I am keeping the break point won't execute, it is shifting the break point automatically. We can normally see that, the local variable declaration section will be skipped, even if we add break point there, and the break point will be shifted to the next line.