# Visual Studio doesn't recognize boolean as variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, scope, visual-studio-debugging

I want to break when test2 is true. It won't let me set a breakpoint inside the conditional where test2 is set to true. So I tried to put a conditional breakpoint below where test3 is declared:

```
        string teststring = "debug";
        bool threedistinct = false;
        bool test2 = false;
        if(teststring.find("d") != string::npos)
            threedistinct = true;
        if(threedistinct)
            test2 = true;

        bool test3 = false;
```

and I get the following errors: 
[image: error1]

[image: error2]

I don't understand how test2 could be undefined. I tried changing its type to int, initialized it to 1, and change its value in the conditional, but I got the same errors. Note: the errors appear only when I try to set the breakpoint.

Comment: It would be nice if you could include a [mcve], so that we can try it out too and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Did you save the file, after adding the `test2` variable? Since, from screenshot, it looks that you didn't save it.

Comment: Instead of a snippet, present your [MCVE] as instructed.

Comment: Ok, I will edit it.

Comment: Are you compiling in release or debug mode? Depending on the optimization level, test2 might be stripped out.

Comment: Agreed if this is a release build this behavior is very understandable. `test2` may not even exist in a release build.

Comment: I was accidentally compiling in max liability mode. I changed to ReleaseDebug and it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Itried Please [read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348983/explicitly-initialize-dword-to-1-but-debugger-shows-wildly-out-of-range-value/23349047#23349047).  You didn't have to change the configuration -- you could have just changed the settings in the current project to disable optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I was accidentally compiling in max liability mode. I changed to Release to Debug and it works. Thanks!"

Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. But I agree with PaulMcKenzie's suggestion, the real issue would be related to certain settings during two different mode which couldn't generate the debugging informaiton.

(1The linker setting which will generate debugging information.
(2)Disable the optimizations option.

A reference about the similar issue:

http://www.databasesql.info/article/896010299/