# how to search a QString in QVector

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qvector

I have been trying search an id a string saved in QVector like this

```
QVector<QString> logMessages;
 
logMessages.append("1- Message");
logMessages.append("2- Message");
logMessages.append("3- Message");
logMessages.append("4- Message");
```

I have tried to use the find but it didn't work with me, the IDE doesn't show any error messages, but in the debug windwo the value of " iterator display "not accessible".

This is what I have tried so far but, it didn't work with me.

```
QVector<QString>::iterator it = std::find(logMessages.begin(), logMessages.end(), "2");
if(it != logMessages.end())
{
    int index = std::distance(logMessages.begin(), it);
}
```

Comment: QVector<QString>::iterator it = std::find(logMessages.begin(), logMessages.end(), "2- Message");

Comment: @OP I'm inclined to close this as a typo, unless you verify that you're actually trying to find `"2"` instead of `"2- Message"`.

Comment: i have already tried this approach but it didn't work with me it gives me the same return value which is the "iterator not accessible", plus i only need to search the index not the full message because it will be different.

Comment: You should quote the exact error message, iterator cannot be accessed is not particularly informative.

Comment: @MohammadA.Dkman `std::find` (if you can make it work) is only going to find the full message, not part of it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually what i need is the index of the message not the complete line as i have mentioned above.

Comment: if you only need to find the index, you should only store the index in said container. You could also look for std::search to find a subsequence

Comment: @MohammadA.Dkman This is not very clear. "iterator not accessible" sounds like a compiler error message, but above you say it's a 'return value'. What do you really mean? Try to be precise when you describe the problem.

Comment: @john the IDE doesn't show any error message, the message I'm talking about is displayed in the debugger window.

Comment: @MohammadA.Dkman OK that helps. Which line of code triggers that message in the debugger?

Comment: ok so the value of `it` is logMessages.end() and the message is displayed by the `else` part of code following what he posted. Bottom line is we need more information to help you. Are you modifying the QStrings held by the QVector ? if not, you need to find whole sequence of characters or use std::search

Comment: @MohammadA.Dkman -- "Iterator not accessible" sounds like you are debugging a release build, or a build that has been optimized in some way.  If so, that is *not* a bug.  You will know if it is an actual runtime bug or not by actually running your program and seeing if your program at that point fails to work properly.

Comment: I'm guessing but I think the fundamental issue is that you are expecting `std::find` to be able to find part of a string that is held in your vector. E.g. you expect `"2"` to be able to find `"2 - message"`. But it doesn't work like that. `std::find` will find exact matches only.

Comment: @john instead of the index value inside of the if() statement i was using qDebug() to debug the value.

Comment: @MohammadA.Dkman Right, so we've established that `std::find` is failing to find anything, and your iterator equals `logMessages.end()` which is not accessible as your debugger says. So I suppose the only issue now is, are you expecting to be able to find a string like "2 - Message" by using a search string of "2", because, as I said, that isn't going to work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry but i didn't get what do you want to say.

Comment: @john so is there any walk around this?

Comment: @MohammadA.Dkman -- 1) Does your program work?  It is still not clear what issue you are having, a non-working program, or a debugger you are trying to use.  2) [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348983/explicitly-initialize-dword-to-1-but-debugger-shows-wildly-out-of-range-value/23349047#23349047)

Comment: You could try `std::find_if` which lets you specify a more complicated condition for finding something, or you could just write a for loop and an if statement. The latter is simpler if you're a beginner.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 1) it does work, but the only thing is that i'm just stuck with the search for the sub string. 2) now i got it, actually the debug function works with no issues i think i'm just not using find() or search appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem

The iterator not being accessible, probably means the iterator points to the end of the vector, i.e. the element is not being found in the vector.

### The solution

The problem is that [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), searches an exact match, i.e. it uses the [`QString::operator == (const char *)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#operator-eq-eq-1) (see [Comparing strings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#comparing-strings)).

You are looking for a string which [starts with](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#startsWith) "2-". Therefore you have to specify a custom equality check, using `std::find_if` and f.ex. a lambda function:

```
QVector<QString>::iterator it = std::find_if(logMessages.begin(), logMessages.end(), [](const QString& s){
  return s.startsWith("2-"); // check if the element starts with "2-"
});
```

### Performance consideration

Note that using `std::find_if` is slow (for large arrays) as it has `O(N)` performance. Using a `QHash<int /*id*/, QString /*message*/>` structure may improve your lookup performance.

Comment: I have just used startsWith() function which solved my problem. thank you very much @m7913d