# Can't understand this selection-sort algorithm, what causes loop to stop and swap? C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, selection-sort

I dont understand how the inner for loop just stops after it finds a value that passes the test expression in the if statement. I was expecting the inner for loop to continue iterating REGARDLESS of whether or not the value at the current iteration satisfies the test expression in the if statement.

I expected this to happen because in the inner loop header it appears to me that as long as index is less than the size of the array it should continue iterating, however it does not continue and jumps back to the outer loop to perform the swap...

I don't get what is stopping the inner for loop from iterating for every single value in every single element regardless of whether it passes the test expression in the if statement. Can anyone clear that up?

Thanks

```cpp
void selectionSor(int array[], int size)
{
     int minIndex, minValue;
     for (int start = 0; start < (size - 1); start++)
     {
          minIndex = start;
          minValue = array[start];
          for (int index = start + 1; index < size; index++)
          {
               if (array[index] < minValue)
               {
               minValue = array[index];
               minIndex = index;
               }
          }
     
        swap(array[minIndex], array[start]);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the inner loop is stopping early?

Comment: *I don't get what is stopping the inner for loop from iterating for every single value in every single element regardless of whether it passes the test expression in the if statement.* -- This could be answered by yourself if you stepped through the code with a debugger.

Comment: The inner loop will stop if `index >= size`.  There is no magic going on.

Comment: This is exactly what your debugger is for. Your debugger will allow you to execute this program, step by step, one line at a time, and inspect the values of all variables and monitor how they change. Have you tried using your debugger already, and if not, why not? If you did, what did you see, that's unclear to you?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz This code shouldn't be wrong since it is an example straight from my textbook.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I dont understand what specific mechanism causes the inner for loop to stop and jump to the swap function as soon as it finds a value less than its neighboring value in the array.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik How do I use the debugger in VisualStudio?

Comment: @sweetdeath97 -- As the first comment stated, how are you determining what that code is doing?  Are you a victim of [debugging a release/optimized build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348983/explicitly-initialize-dword-to-1-but-debugger-shows-wildly-out-of-range-value/23349047#23349047)?  Also, how about a [mcve], so we can see what you're claiming you're seeing.

Comment: You're in luck! Visual Studio has one of the easiest-to-use debuggers out there. [I'd start reading here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @sweetdeath97 I don't see any mechanism for that either, which is why I asked why you think there is one.

Comment: I'm with Jeremy. The behaviour described by the code is the same as what you expect. If it's doing anything different, things broke very badly somewhere else.

Comment: @sweetdeath97 If you are using a debugger, *and* the code is not optimized, then the only way your claim holds water is in the case of undefined behavior, i.e. accessing that array out-of-bounds, possibly clobbering other variables.

Comment: Removing that brace results in non-compliable code. Either `for (int start = 0; start < (size - 1); start++)` no longer has a close brace or the function doesn't, depending on how you look at it.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner ok, so I guess I am just reading too far into it? So it in fact does iterate for every member of the array and just sends what is assigned to minValue and minIndex to swap AFTER  a complete iteration of the inner for loop? I guess my textbook confused me somehow...(i'm new to this) Also this is just a small snippet of code from my textbook for demonstration purposes of the selection-sort algorithm. There is no other code.

Comment: Make sure your code exactly duplicate what is in the book and then use the debugger to step through the function line-by-line to see exactly what the program does. If you also watch the variables in play you'll see why it chose to do what it did. The debugger is te second most effective programmer tool out there, right after the compiler.

Comment: @sweetdeath97 `for (int index = start + 1; index < size; index++)` -- It doesn't matter if the code is a selection sort, or a video game loop.  The loop stops when `index >= size` -- there is no other way for that loop to terminate.  If you're asking why the loop works, that's a different story.  But asking why the loop stops -- that's the reason why -- no other reason.

Comment: Shoot. If there is no other code, you'll have to work through it pen-and-paper style or write a really simple `main` function that calls `selectionSor`, compile that and then start stepping.

Comment: @user4581301 I will try that thanks

Comment: Quick hack example: https://ideone.com/CTEcql

Comment: @user4581301 wow you are an angel, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Ok silly question @user4581301 , but I've opened the code you sent me in VS, but I am not sure how to run it.. Do I have to copy/paste it into a new project to run it or is there a simpler way?

Comment: @user4581301 Nevermind I figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

selection sort performs fewer exchanges because it moves items immediately to their final position in array. it works like: smallest value in array is located and moved to element 0. then next smallest value is located and moved to element 1. this process continues until all elements have been placed in their proper order. so, 1 stored in element 5 is swapped with 5 stored in element 0. algorithm then repeats process, but element 0 already contains smallest value in array so, it can be left out. so, algorithm begins scan at element 1 then element 2 then element 3 then other all elements. pseudocode: For startScan is set to each subscript in array from 0 through next-to-last subscript→Set index variable to startScan. →Set minIndex variable to startScan. →Set minValue variable to array[startScan]. →For index is set to each subscript in array from (startScan + 1) through last subscript→If array[index] is less than minValue→Set minValue to array[index]. →Set minIndex to index. →End If. →End For. →Set array[minIndex] to array[startScan]. →Set array[startScan] to minValue. →End For. inner for loop sequences through array, starting at array [startScan + 1], searching for element with smallest value. when element is found, its subscript is stored in variable minIndex and its value is stored in minValue. outer loop then exchanges contents of this element with array[startScan] and increments startScan. this procedure repeats until contents of every element have been moved to their proper location.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).