# Why does debugger start to jump arbitrary after if-statement?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

My problem occurs when debugging this function.

```
std::vector<patch_bundle> clean_up(std::vector<patch_bundle> vc){
    
    cout << "girdim ha";    
        for(auto itr = vc.begin(); itr != vc.end();){
    
            patch_bundle cmp_patch_bundle = *itr;
        string cmp_indices = cmp_patch_bundle.patch1_name;
        for(auto i_itr = vc.begin(); i_itr != vc.end();){
            if(i_itr != itr){
                patch_bundle tmp_patch_bundle = *i_itr; 
                string indices1 = tmp_patch_bundle.patch1_name;
                string indices2 = tmp_patch_bundle.patch2_name;
                if((indices1 == cmp_indices) || (indices2 == cmp_indices)){

                    vc.erase(i_itr);
                 }
                else{
                   ++i_itr;
                 }

               
             }
            else{
               ++i_itr;
             }
            
         }
        ++itr;
        
    }
 }
```

`patch_bundle` is `struct` as follows:

```
struct patch_bundle{
    int patch1[4] = {0,0,0,0};
    int patch2[4] = {0,0,0,0};
    std::string patch1_name;
    std::string patch2_name;

    std::string patch1_label;
    std::string patch2_label;

 };
```

Here is the debugger output:

```
Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, clean_up (vc=std::vector of length 5400, capacity 5400 = {...}) at test.cpp:338
338             cout << "girdim ha";
(gdb) n
girdim ha339                    for(auto itr = vc.begin(); itr != vc.end();){
(gdb)
341                     patch_bundle cmp_patch_bundle = *itr;
(gdb)
342                     string cmp_indices = cmp_patch_bundle.patch1_name;
(gdb)
343                     for(auto i_itr = vc.begin(); i_itr != vc.end();){
(gdb)
344                             if(i_itr != itr){
(gdb)
359                                ++i_itr;
(gdb)
343                     for(auto i_itr = vc.begin(); i_itr != vc.end();){
(gdb)
344                             if(i_itr != itr){
(gdb)
345                                     patch_bundle tmp_patch_bundle = *i_itr;
(gdb)
346                                     string indices1 = tmp_patch_bundle.patch1_name;
(gdb)
347                                     string indices2 = tmp_patch_bundle.patch2_name;
(gdb)
**348                                     if((indices1 == cmp_indices) || (indices2 == cmp_indices)){
**(gdb)
353                                        ++i_itr;
(gdb)
347                                     string indices2 = tmp_patch_bundle.patch2_name;
(gdb) n
346                                     string indices1 = tmp_patch_bundle.patch1_name;
(gdb)
345                                     patch_bundle tmp_patch_bundle = *i_itr;
(gdb)
344                             if(i_itr != itr){
(gdb)
345                                     patch_bundle tmp_patch_bundle = *i_itr;
(gdb)
346                                     string indices1 = tmp_patch_bundle.patch1_name;
(gdb)
```

Then below the bold line, the `indices2` is read off first than `indices1`. It seems weird. What could be the reason?

It is worth-noting that I initially was using just standard `for(int itr = 0; ..;...)` type of iteration. The problem was occuring after the same bold line. So my guess is that memory-wise something is not quite right. But would it affect `gdb`'s behavior?

I am looking for providing more information if needed.

Thank you.

Comment: Off topic (maybe), but are you aware that `std::vector<patch_bundle> clean_up(std::vector<patch_bundle> vc)` is working with a *copy* of the vector `vc` and not the vector that you passed in?  I see a lot of stuff going on with `vc`, and it gives the impression that you expected the passed-in vector to be changed (when it won't be).

Comment: Apart from memory "not quite right", the type of behaviour you see is reasonably common (and somewhat normal) if your code was compiled with optimisation (which can reorganise the order in which things are done) or without debugging information (which affects ability of the debugger to keep track of what line of code is reached).

Comment: *What could be the reason?* -- Even though this answer is more specific to Visual C++ [the same issue will happen with your debugger if you compiled your code with optimizations turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348983/explicitly-initialize-dword-to-1-but-debugger-shows-wildly-out-of-range-value/23349047#23349047).

Answer (score 2):

When you observe that GDB steps into these lines:

```
353                                        ++i_itr;
(gdb)
347                                     string indices2 = tmp_patch_bundle.patch2_name;
(gdb) n
346                                     string indices1 = tmp_patch_bundle.patch1_name;
```

you see it execute the destructor of `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably experiencing this GCC bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88742. I assume you are using GCC for compilation. The solution can be to update GCC to a more recent version or use Clang. From bug description GCC is known to fail on 10.5.0, 5.5.0, 6.4.0, 7.3.0, 8.2.0, 9.0 versions and known to work on 11.0, 4.7.4, 4.8.5, 4.9.4 versions.